# Mockito Verify : Wanted but not invoked error

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am actually trying to do below:
My service class

```
 @Service   
    public class serviceclass{
    
    @Autowired  
    MessageReplyingSender rclass;
    
    public void doMethod(){
    Object o = rlcass.something("hey","hey",null,1000);
    }
    }
    
    public interface MessageReplyingSender {
    
        public <T> Object something(String sendertopic,T message,Map<String, Object> headers, long replyTimeout)
                throws Exception;
    }
    
    
    
    Test Class:  
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)  
    public class testclass{  
    @InjectMocks  
        private serviceclass sclass;
        
        @Mock
        MessageReplyingSender rclass;
    
       public void test throws Exception{
    Mockito.verify(rclass).something(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyLong());

Mockito.when(rclass.something(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn("gh");
sclass.doMethod();
        
            
    }
    }
```

This gives me wanted by not invoked,actually there were Zero interactions with this mock. Any idea what am i doing wrong??

Comment: where do you state the call should throw an Exception?

Comment: @Stultuske I am actually adding throws on test Method, I have edited the code here.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Just adding "throws Exception" to a method signature doesn't mean it will throw an Exception, it means that the implementation might throw one. You're mocking it in such a way that it doesn't throw an exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're verifying that `rclass#something` is called. But that's not happening because you forgot to trigger it with `serviceclass#doMethod`

Comment: I am doing that, i just added that code here.

Comment: Yes, but the order matters. You have to do the verify after triggering it :)

So, the order should be:
1) Mock the when(..)
2) Trigger it with serviceclass#doMethod
3) Do the verify of rclass#something